# Is it faster to hide by style.display or copy entire DIV?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a presentation in html. It is supposed to be something like powerpoint in MS Office. It will have **preview** of all the slides and **one slide at a time will be displayed** across the window. I do have a list of slides and am able to play with them via Javascript. I am able to shrink them into the preview.

**Concerning the one slide that is shown:** 
I wonder whether it would be better to have a copy of all the shown slides within one wrapper div and make them visible one by one by setting the display property. Or if it would be better to copy one slide at a time into this wrapper div.

For clarity... I get something like this

```
<body>
 <div class="slide">/*slide stuff*/</div>
 <div class="slide">/*slide stuff*/</div>
 <div class="slide">/*slide stuff*/</div>
 <div class="slide">/*slide stuff*/</div>
</body>
```

I convert it into this

```
<body>
 <div id=preview>
  <div class="slide" id="1">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="2">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="3">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="4">/*slide stuff*/</div>
 </div>
 ...
```

Now should I display them rather by changing the display property. So the html continues like this:

```
...
 <div id="mainwindow">
  <div class="slide" id="p1" display="none">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="p2" display="none">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="p3" display="none">/*slide stuff*/</div>
  <div class="slide" id="p4" display="none">/*slide stuff*/</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Or should I just make the `mainwindow` div empty and copy the slide into it on every slide change?

```
...
 <div id="mainwindow">
 </div>
</body>
```

Please I would appreciate any comment on the speed of both solutions (if the slides are packed with other tags), and since it is school assignment I wonder what solution would be considered "cleaner" and/or more "Pro".

Comment: You may want to try benchmark it on jsperf.com

Comment: Are you merely creating this as a "one off" or would you actually be creating a framework to deliver any presentation? But I agree with Dogbert - benchmark it

Comment: The idea is to have one script + one css sheet that could be attached to any html file containing divs with class="slide"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `element.style.display` to hide would be much faster than copying an element when you went to the next slide. Copying requires changing the DOM which is always more costly than simply hiding an element.

The only instance I can see where this is not the case would be when you have on the order of hundreds of slides. The shear size of the page could become slow the browser.